# Converter Query SQL Server para Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Como converter uma `SQL` do `SQL Server` para `Entity Framework`, Ordenando os valores do campo da seguinte maneira:

de:

```
({'115-F-G', '10 -H-G ', '98 -T-R'})
```

para:

```
('10 -H-G ','98 -T-R','115-F-G')
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM ReportePedido Where PedidoId = 145
Order By TipoProducto, 
         CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(EnderecoEstoque, 0, CHARINDEX('-',EnderecoEstoque,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria essa a query:

```
var res = (from x in Contexto.Set<ReportePedido>()
                  where x.PedidoId == 145
                  orderby x.EnderecoEstoque.Substring(0, x.EnderecoEstoque.IndexOf('-'))
                  select x);
```